# Make bar/progress chart with JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have data like displayed on top of the image. Is it posible to make a diagran like this (picture), with pure JS, CSS and HTML? I dont know what a diagram/chart like this is called. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You could use (and style it accordingly) an input `type="range"` - or just use a DIV. And PS, total and only one other param is needed. There's multiple ways to achieve that. by using a background with CSS `background-position`... or using `::before` etc etc etc. What have you tried so far?

Comment: FWIW this type of chart is usually referred to as a stacked bar chart.

Comment: [Are "Point me in the right direction" questions acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/are-point-me-in-the-right-direction-questions-acceptable)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript.
Pass a CSS [var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()) from HTML to CSS and use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) to get the percentages

### Using background linear gradient

```css
.progress {
  background: green;
  height: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green calc(var(--val) * 10%), red calc(var(--val) * 10%));
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="--val:1"></div><br>
<div class="progress" style="--val:7"></div><br>
```

### Using CSS pseudo element ::before

```css
.progress {
  background: red;
  height: 2em;
}
.progress::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  background: green;
  width: calc(var(--val) * 10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="--val:1"></div><br>
<div class="progress" style="--val:7"></div><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach is to use an absolutely positioned child in a relatively positioned parent and set its width as the progress.

```js
function setProgress(percent) {
  const range = document.querySelector('.range');
  const progress = range.querySelector('.progress');
  
  progress.style.width = `${percent}%`
}

setProgress(70);
```

```css
.range {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ed3a23;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4db24c;
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's pure HTML & CSS

```css
.bar-wrap {
  display: flex
}
.col {
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  width: var(--size)
}
.bar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: var(--background)
}
.cgreen {
  color: green
}
.cred {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-wrap">
  <div class="col cgreen" style="--size:70%;">
    <h3 class="heading">Correct</h3>
    <div class="bar" style="--background:green"></div>
    <p class="label">70%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col cred" style="--size:30%;">
    <h3 class="heading">Wrong</h3>
    <div class="bar" style="--background:red"></div>
    <p class="label">30%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To meet accessibility and semantic code standards, I'd recommend having a look into the HTML `<meter>` element ([official specification with all the attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-meter-element)). Or you just have a look on [HTML5 doctor](http://html5doctor.com/measure-up-with-the-meter-tag/) to get a more compact/short conclusion.

However, keep in mind that according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=meter), legacy browsers like Edge 12 and others don't support this HTML tag. So if you want to support these older browsers, that are listed there as non-supporting, you would need to come up with a fallback solution.

### Rough code example for a fallback solution

```
<div class="meter-wrapper">
  <div class="meter" style="width: 70%;">
    <!-- `hidden` attribute to hide the text content but keeping the element accessible for screen readers. -->
    <p class="meter__text-fallback meter__text-fallback--correct"><strong>70%</strong><span hidden>of given answers are correct.</span></p>
  </div>
  <p class="meter__text-fallback meter__text-fallback--incorrect"><strong>30%</strong><span hidden>of given answers are incorrect.</span></p>
</div>
```

and style it something like this:

```
/* CSS */
.meter-wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.meter {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: MediumAquamarine;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.meter__text-fallback {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: -25px;
}

/* This class block is not utterly necessary, since the default value for `left` is already `0`. Just in case you want to have different values. */
.meter__text-fallback--correct {
  left: 0;
}

.meter__text-fallback--incorrect {
  right: 0;
}
```

#### See this code example in action

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Kayzah/pen/QWOxYpB)

#### Important notes to this code example

1. I would recommend to change your layout from having the percentage of correct and incorrect answers *outside* the meter bars to avoid a case, where you would have a slimmer bar than the width of the typography overlapping it.
2. Setting the values for the `style="width: 70%"` attributes would need to be controlled via JS.
   It is also arguable to style HTML elements with inline styles, like I did in this example. On the other hand creating a 100+ different CSS classes for such a case, might be overkill. Styling via `data` attributes is also not fully supported. So I'll leave this decision up to you.